# Python: Remove string value from row if two other columns contain 'No' string in same row

Tags: python, string, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have the following sample table below in a pandas dataframe.

```
Col1       Col2        Col3     Col4          Col5
                       No       4/30/2018     No
                       No       4/30/2018     No
Await AIR  7/15/2015   Yes      4/30/2018     No
Await LER  7/15/2015   No       4/30/2018     No
Await TEE  7/15/2015   No       4/30/2018     No
```

The logic I want to implement is as follows: 
If Col3 is 'No' AND Col5 is 'No' I want to remove the string in Col1 (if it is not blank already) and make it blank.

Below is my desired output table:

```
Col1       Col2        Col3     Col4          Col5
                       No       4/30/2018     No
                       No       4/30/2018     No
Awaiting   7/15/2015   Yes      4/30/2018     No
           7/15/2015   No       4/30/2018     No
           7/15/2015   No       4/30/2018     No
```

I think I have the if statement but don't know how to code the remainder of my logic:

```
if df_EVENT5_21['shipping_filter'] == 'No' and df_EVENT5_21['shipping_filter_2'] == 'No':
    ...
```

Comment: It's helpful if you add a sample df so people who answer can test out their responses prior to posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Col1'] = np.where( ((df['Col3 '] == 'No') & (df['Col5'] == 'No']) ), '', df['Col1'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `pd.DataFrame.mask`

```
df[['Col1']].mask(df[['Col3', 'Col5']].eq('No').all(1), '')

        Col1
0           
1           
2  Await AIR
3           
4
```

---

We can pipeline this with `pd.DataFrame.assign`

```
df.assign(
    **df[['Col1']].mask(df[['Col3', 'Col5']].eq('No').all(1), '')
)

        Col1       Col2 Col3       Col4 Col5
0                         No  4/30/2018   No
1                         No  4/30/2018   No
2  Await AIR  7/15/2015  Yes  4/30/2018   No
3             7/15/2015   No  4/30/2018   No
4             7/15/2015   No  4/30/2018   No
```

---

Or in place with `pd.DataFrame.update`

```
df.update(df[['Col1']].mask(df[['Col3', 'Col5']].eq('No').all(1), ''))
df

        Col1       Col2 Col3       Col4 Col5
0                         No  4/30/2018   No
1                         No  4/30/2018   No
2  Await AIR  7/15/2015  Yes  4/30/2018   No
3             7/15/2015   No  4/30/2018   No
4             7/15/2015   No  4/30/2018   No
```

---

**Alternatively without the double brackets**

```
df.assign(
    Col1=df.Col1.mask(df[['Col3', 'Col5']].eq('No').all(1), '')
)
```

Or

```
df.update(df.Col1.mask(df[['Col3', 'Col5']].eq('No').all(1), ''))
df
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `.loc` accessor with a mask:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['', '', 'AWait AIR', 'Await LER', 'Await TEE'],
                   'Col2': ['', '', '7/15/2015', '7/15/2015', '7/15/2015'],
                   'Col3': ['No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No'],
                   'Col4': ['4/30/2018', '4/30/2018', '4/30/2018', '4/30/2018', '4/30/2018'],
                   'Col5': ['No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No']})

df.loc[(df[['Col3', 'Col5']] == 'No').all(axis=1), 'Col1'] = ''

#         Col1       Col2 Col3       Col4 Col5
# 0                         No  4/30/2018   No
# 1                         No  4/30/2018   No
# 2  AWait AIR  7/15/2015  Yes  4/30/2018   No
# 3             7/15/2015   No  4/30/2018   No
# 4             7/15/2015   No  4/30/2018   No
```

**Explanation**

The inspiration for this solution is `numpy` logic to create Boolean arrays:

```
(df[['Col3', 'Col5']].values == 'No').all(axis=1)

# array([ True,  True, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: In my opinion, this should not be down voted.  This is a perfectly valid and good pandas answer.  Future readers should consider this as a viable option if it suits their needs.